# How to secure scripting with JSR 223?

Tags: java, security, groovy, scriptengine, jsr223

I use Groovy as dynamic script engine to allow admin users of my web application to create little scripts as part of an interface solution, eg. do simple string operations, tokenize and so on.
Unfortunately that opens quite a big loophole because per default the script engine would execute anything.
I described a demo app here: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-a-zk-groovy-console/

```
Object value = shell.evaluate("whatever groovy script");
```

You can execute `System.exit(0)` which shuts down the AS or even shell commands like `"ls -l".execute().text`or just snoop around system settings `println InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress`

I could do a string check before executing, like filter for `System.xyz` or `execute.xyz`

Comment: You could also check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681413/how-do-you-forbid-users-from-doing-evil-things-in-groovy-scripts/36706404#36706404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With groovy 1.8, you can customize the compiler configuration

There's a [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20170406123714/http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/customizing_groovy_compilation_process) here which explains more.

You should aso read:

- http://kohsuke.org/2012/04/27/groovy-secureastcustomizer-is-harmful/
- http://kohsuke.org/2012/04/29/potd-groovy-sandbox/